# How to decrease rotation speed in qml depending from the time?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I need to create something like fortune wheel in qml. I know how to use rotation animation but i cant make decreasing rotation speed depending from the time. And this animation at finally should be stopped without user interaction. What I should use in this case?

Comment: Use a timer to change the rotation.

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Comment: You could use a custom easing curve.

Comment: I have tried. Maybe I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Frank Osterfeld already said that so I just put here a small example:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    radius: 100
    clip: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "yellow"
    Text {
        text: "+"
        font.pixelSize: 200
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    PropertyAnimation on rotation {
        from: 0
        to: 3600
        duration: 10000
        running: true
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
    }
}
```